# Do we add measurement uncertainty to confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, measurement-error

If my mean has a measurement uncertainty, is it necessary to add that onto the confidence interval? Since the equation for confidence interval is x±ts/√n.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It all comes down to what you mean by "$s:$" if it is an estimated standard deviation based on observations of the measured values, then it already incorporates the effects of measurement uncertainty.  But if it's estimated (or specified) in some other way, then the answer might change.